# About algebraic groups defined over Q

Tags: algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms

I'm studying automorphic forms and there's something I don't understand, when we talk about a connected reductive algebraic group $G$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, connected means connected as an algebraic group when we consider the corresponding complex algebraic group $G_\mathbb{C}$ obtained by extension of scalars?

Comment: Connectedness of a $\mathbb{Q}$-variety with a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point is equivalent to connectedness of the corresponding $\mathbb{C}$-variety obtained by base change over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: To clarify further: In the Borel-Tits language for reductive algebraic groups defined over an arbitrary field $k$, the algebraic group $G$ itself exists apart from mentioning a field of definition (which is not unique).   Connectedness just refers to the Zariski topology on $G$ without reference to $k$.   Similar observations can be made in the scheme-theoretic setting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you please give a reference where I can read how the Zarisky topology on ´G´ is defined (without reference to ´k´) because I just know the Zarisky topology on algebrac groups (or algebraic varieties) in its set of points in an algebraic closed field.

Answer (score 1):

Over $\mathbb{Q}$, connectedness usually means no nontrivial finite quotient.

See for example Milne's notes on [Reductive Groups](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/RG.pdf).